# How to construct Lorentz invariant quantities from a set of Lorentz tensors?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

This is all the information given in this question. I have no idea how to build these Loerntz invariants. How would I go about answering this? 
[image]

Comment: Think about what it means to be "Lorentz invariant" in regards to the indices of a tensor..

Comment: @Sito Well I know what Lorentz invariant means, where laws of physics doesn't change depending on the frame. I know what tensors do. I am still unsure on how to move forward thought.

Comment: @NathanaelFisher - a scalar does not change as you change coordinates. How can you build scalars out of these tensors? Also, can you use metric tensor as well as these tensors?

Comment: Strictly speaking, one must use the metric tensor to build invariant [scalars] with what was given... although "raising and lower indices" will hide the underlying use of the metric.

Answer (score 1):

A Lorentz invariant is what we call a Lorentz scalar. Scalars don't have any upper or lower indices.

For example, the 4-momentum $p^\mu$ is a Lorentz vector because it transforms the way a vector $V^\mu$ transforms, i.e $p'^\mu=\Lambda^\mu_\nu p^\nu$. A Lorentz scalar on the other hand stays the same when performing a Lorentz transformation $m'=m$. Here $m$ can be thought of as the mass of some particle.

If you contract a vector with a vector you get a scalar, $p^\mu p_\mu=m^2$ where $m$ is the mass. This is a Lorentz invariant because $p^\mu$ transforms as a contravariant vector while $p_\mu$ transforms as a covariant vector $$p'^\mu p'_\mu = \Lambda^\mu_\nu p^\nu \Lambda^\sigma_\mu p_\sigma = p^\mu p_\mu$$ where I have used $\Lambda^\mu_\nu\Lambda^\sigma_\mu = \delta^\sigma_\nu$.

So you can think about all possible contractions you can make from those given tensors, $T^{\mu\nu}$ and $a^\mu$.

Comment: I see. So would $$a'^\mu a'_\mu = \Lambda^\mu_\nu a^\nu \Lambda^\sigma_\mu a_\sigma = a^\mu a_\mu$$ be one of Lorentz invariant in my case?

Comment: Yes, $a^\mu a_\mu$ is a Lorentz invariant. Now you think about other contractions. You should also note the importance of having a **symmetric** tensor in this question. You will have less than 5 Lorentz invariants if for example $T^{\mu\nu}$ was antisymmetric.

Answer (score 0):

Just combine tensors in a way that all Lorentz indices are contracted e.g $a_\mu a^\mu$, $a_\mu a_\nu T^{\mu\nu}$, $T^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}$ etc.

Comment: As I need five Lorentz invariants, would these five be suffice then: $a_\mu a^\mu$, $a_\mu a_\nu T^{\mu\nu}$, $T^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}$, $a_\nu a^\nu$, $a_\nu T_{\mu\nu}$

Comment: The fourth is identical to the first one and the fifth is not a scalar. You need two more.

Comment: $a^\mu a_\mu$ is the same as $a^\nu a_\nu$. $\mu$ and $\nu$ are what we call dummy indices, it's just a label. For example $$\int_0^1 x^2 dx = \int_0^1 y^2dy$$ $x$ and $y$ are just labels.

Comment: @GiorgioComitini I see! So what would the other two be?

Comment: @Pinkman98 That helps a lot, I like that concept of seeing them as that example.

Comment: @NathanaelFisher Look at what Giorgio Comitini says! You can also build things like $a_\mu T^{\mu\rho} T_{\rho\sigma} a^\sigma$.

Comment: @NathanaelFisher Also the symmetry of your tensor adds another scalar, $T^\mu_\mu$ the trace.

Comment: @Pinkman98 Sorry, I really am trying to understand this. would $a^\mu a^\nu T_{\mu\nu}$ be the same as $a_\mu a_\nu T^{\mu\nu}$

Comment: @NathanaelFisher yes they are the same. In general $$V^\mu V^\nu S_{\mu\nu}= V_\mu V_\nu S^{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\sigma}\eta_{\nu\rho}V^\mu V^\nu S^{\sigma\rho} = \eta^{\mu\sigma}\eta^{\nu\rho}V_\mu V_\nu S_{\sigma\rho}.$$ You can switch here $\mu$ and $\sigma$ together or $\nu$ and $\rho$ if you want because of symmetry.

Comment: @Pinkman98 I am glad I got that! Can you have $a^\mu a^\mu T^{\mu\mu}$

Comment: @NathanaelFisher No, contraction happens between an upper and lower indice. This is important for invariance as I mentioned in my first answer.